How to Configure Laravel Pulse to Monitor API Requests in a Laravel Backend?
I'm working on a Laravel backend that serves as an API for my React Native Expo app. I want to use Laravel Pulse to monitor all incoming API requests, track slow queries, and list users who are using the API.
I'm not sure how to configure Laravel Pulse to monitor these incoming API requests. Can anyone guide me on how to set this up?
Thanks in advance!

I have posted my detailed answer. Please check and let me know.


I'm not sure how to configure Laravel Pulse to monitor these incoming API requests. Can anyone guide me on how to set this up?

Here I am giving you a step by step idea about how to install and use the pulse package.
At first, you need to install the Pulse package using composer like this.
composer require laravel/pulse

Then publish the pulse configuration & migrations file using the command
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Laravel\Pulse\PulseServiceProvider"

Then you need to run migrate command to create table needed to store pulse data
php artisan migrate

Once the pulse database migration file run,you can access the pulse dashboard via /pulse route.
Now in order to monitor the incoming API requests, track slow queries, and list users who are using the API , you will need to publish the config/pulse.php configuration file with this command
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=pulse-config

After publishing the config.php file you need to register the each recorder(Recorders are registered and configured in the recorders section of pulse.php config file) that you want to use(in your case  incoming API requests, track slow queries etc.).

To get the detailed information about slow-query you can visit the docs
link given below.
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/pulse#slow-queries-card

To monitor all incoming API requests, you can visit the below link.
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/pulse#slow-requests-recorder


Note :-
1. To use the card(you will get idea about it in docs) you need to run this following command on individual application server.
php artisan pulse:check

2. For more general details about pulse you can visit the official docs link given below.
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/pulse
Try the above mentioned steps it will work for sure. Remember to configure the each recorder in correct way in the pulse.php config file which is also given in the official docs.
